# How to speed up for loops for classes? Using begin() or for loop

Tags: c++, iteration

How can I speed up `char*`/class iterations?
I have some demo code testing the speed of iterations.

Yet I do not understand why iterating a char array is so slow when using `begin()`, and much faster when using `for (int = 0; i < n; ++i) {...}`.

I am using `g++ gnu++2a` & `macos`.

`base::string` is my custom class.

Code:

```cpp
class Iterator {
public:
    const unsigned char *values;
    int n;
    int index = 0;
    Iterator(int n__, const unsigned char *v) {
        n = n__;
        values = v;
    }
    auto& ref() { return *this; }
    auto& ref() const { return *this; }
    auto& begin() { return ref(); }
    auto& cbegin() const { return ref(); }
    auto& end() { return ref(); }
    auto& cend() const { return ref(); }
    bool operator !=(const Iterator& x) { return index < n; }
    bool operator !=(const Iterator & x) const { return index < n; }
    auto& operator ++() { ++index; return ref(); }
};

int main() {
    using namespace cinc;
    using namespace cinc::utils;
    long mark;

    // Itrings.
    print("Speed test:");
    print("   - initialize:");
    mark = timestamp();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        std::string x;
        x = "";
    }
    print("     - std::string:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");
    mark = timestamp();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        base::string x;
        x = "";
    }
    print("     - base::string:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");

    // Append.
    print("   - append:");
    mark = timestamp();
    std::string std_string;
    std::string std_string_air;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        std_string += "0";
    }
    print("     - std::string:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");
    mark = timestamp();
    base::string base_string;
    base_string.allocate();
    base::string base_string_air;
    base_string_air.allocate();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        base_string.append('0');
    }
    print("     - base::string:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");
    base_string.del();

    // Iterate.
    print("   - iterate:");

    // Iterate std::string with begin.
    mark = timestamp();
    for (auto& i: std_string) {
        std_string_air += i;
    }
    print("     - base::string::begin:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");

    // Iterate base::string with a simlpe for index loop.
    mark = timestamp();
    const unsigned char* us = (unsigned char*)  base_string.values;
    int n = base_string.size__;
    for (int index = 0; index < n; ++index) {
        base_string_air.append(us[index]);
    }
    print("     - base::string::for:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");

    // Iterate base::string with the begin.
    mark = timestamp();
    Iterator iterator = Iterator(base_string.size__, (unsigned char*) base_string.values);
    for (auto& i = iterator.begin(); i != iterator.end(); ++iterator) {
        base_string_air.append(iterator.values[i.index]);
    }
    print("     - base::string::begin:",timestamp() - mark,"ms");
    return 0;

}
```

Output speed test:

```
initialize:
 * std::string: 214 ms
 * base::string: 83 ms
append:
 * std::string: 120 ms
 * base::string: 46 ms
iterate:
 * std::string::begin: 83 ms
 * base::string::for: 22 ms
 * base::string::begin: 94 ms
```

Speed logs using the g++ option '-O2' during compiling:

```
Speed test:
Speed test:
   - initialize:
     - std::string: 58 ms
     - base::string: 0 ms
   - append:
     - std::string: 96 ms
     - base::string: 10 ms
   - iterate:
     - base::string::begin: 34 ms
     - base::string::for: 0 ms
     - base::string::begin: 0 ms
```

Comment: Try repeating your tests with this `g++ -std=gnu++2a -O3 source.cpp -o source`

Comment: What is base::string?

Comment: Could also try `-O2` as well.

Comment: @user3134709 `-O` flag tells the compiler to apply optimizations at concrete level. Without it there is no reason to use C++ at all! It should be safe, unless a compiler has a bug somewhere.

Comment: Also, you have a problem now with your code. The `-O2` flag allows the compiler to remove code that has no visible effect. So for example your final loops have no visible effect outside of the code (reading data and doing nothing with it is meaningless). This means that the compiler is free to completely remove those loops. That's probably why you see `0 ms`. That's not a good way to measure things.

Comment: "_-O2 is bad for execution time_" It doesn't say that. Below the table it states that "--" means "reduce more", and a "more reduced execution time" means improved performance (good).

Comment: @user3134709 this is better. The difference now may come from the fact that you .append to s02air but you don't reset that object. It may happen that the append operation gets slower the bigger the object is due to potential allocations. Try to reset the object before the second loop.

Comment: The purpose of `-O0` is to have running code with an attached debugger, such that you can put breakpoints and where they are triggered still corresponds to your source code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! This looks more like it! Supa fast (I updated the code and speed logs again).

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to `base_string_air`. So the string gets longer and longer and will have to reallocate more and more storage.

I the first loop with index the string is small and copying it to the new storage is fast. In the second loop with iterator the string is a lot longer and copying takes more time.

Other than that you have to look at the compiled code to see if your iterator abstraction is optimized away or not.